# How to add dots on line visjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, neural-network, vis.js

I have tried to add additional information to the edges of the network, but it seems I can't do it.

I've tried to do it in multiple ways, but while everything works perfectly fine with nodes, it doesn't work with edges.

For example:
[image]